# No such filter - Error initializing complex filters - Invalid argument

Tags: ffmpeg

My command is

```
ffmpeg -y -i background.mp4 -i overlay.mp4 -filter_complex '[1:a:0]amerge=inputs=1[a];[1:v]colorkey=0x586689:0.1:0.1[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay=x=430:y=50[out]' -map "[out]" -map "[a]" neu.mp4
```

I get

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 000002b0b497b4e0] No such filter: '[1:a:0]amerge=inputs=1[a];[1:v]colorkey=0x586689:0.1:0.1[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay=x=430:y=50[out]'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me on Linux, so I'm guessing it's a Windows problem. Replace `'` with `"`:

```
ffmpeg -y -i background.mp4 -i overlay.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:a:0]amerge=inputs=1[a];[1:v]colorkey=0x586689:0.1:0.1[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay=x=430:y=50[out]" -map "[out]" -map "[a]" neu.mp4
```

Unrelated, but using amerge fiter with 1 input does not do anything so I suggest removing it.